# archive command is not working

Tags: postgresql, archive

One of our ancient PostgreSQL server's used disk space has increased to 90%. First I've checked the archive command:

```
archive_command = 'rsync -aq %p /data/wal-archive/%f'
```

The problem with that command is `rsync` is not installed. So I've replaced it with:

```
archive_command = 'test ! -f /data/pgsql/data/mnt/server/archivedir/%f && 
    cp %p /data/pgsql/data/mnt/server/archivedir/%f'
```

After the replacement here is the output of `postgresql.log`:

> cp: cannot stat `pg_xlog/000000010000000000000001': No such file or directory

I presume beginning of the `pg_xlog` files removed by hand. Do you have any idea how to make this archive process work?

Answer (score 3):

First, take a `pg_basebackup`, just in case. Then set your archive command to `/bin/true`. That will allow Postgres to delete everything to its own satisfaction that has already been deleted. To restore from backup you need the WAL since your last basebackup. Restoring to a point in time before is now impossible I’m afraid. When this is finished, set the archive command correctly. And get some monitoring for this!

Comment: I've moved all of the .ready files to .done in the archive_status directory. All of the wal files removed. Archiving is now working properly i think. I didn't write this as a solution because i don't know the true effects of my actions.